# C code for using qsort() to sort in the order the user wants using function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, function-pointers, qsort

I am creating a C code to sort using qsort(). I need to get an array from the user and after that I need to get a from the user to print this array in ascending order and d if I want to print it in descending order. The problem is that I need to use function pointers to do this. I tried to use an array of function pointers but the problem is that the user needs to enter two characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int  a( const void *va , const void * vb )
 {
    const int * a = ( const int *) va ;
    const int * b = ( const int *) vb ;
    if (* a < *b ) return -1;
    else if (* a > * b) return 1;
    else return 0;
 }

 int  d( const void *va , const void * vb )
 {
    const int * a = ( const int *) va ;
    const int * b = ( const int *) vb ;
    if (* a < *b ) return 1;
    else if (* a > * b) return -1;
    else return 0;
 }


int main()
{
    int *arr;
    int n, i;
    char c;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        getchar();
        if(c=='e')
            break;


        qsort ( arr , n , sizeof(arr[0]) , d);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are plenty of solutions online, search

Comment: Note: common idiom for `a()` --> return `(* a > * b) - (* a < * b);`

Comment: C does not require all those casts. Moreover they may hide errors. Just remove them.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc ) 1) all have a return type of `void *` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  So no need to cast the returned value.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  3) function names best contain an active verb to indicate what they do  `d` and `a` tell the casual reader of the code nothing about the function.

Comment: suggest just one qsort comparison function and keep the user entered indication of ascending/descenting sort in a variable that is visible to the comparison function, then let the function check that variable to determine what it will do.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when the use runs the posted code, all they will see is a blank screen with a blinking cursor and no indication of what to do next.  Always prompt the user so the user knows what to enter.  Then (never trust the user) check the input to assure it is a valid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, declare a pointer-to-function variable `comparison_func`, and set it in an `if` statement:

```
int (*comparison_func)(const void *, const void *);

if (c == 'a') {
    comparison_func = a;
}
else if (c == 'c') {
    comparison_func = d;
}
```

then use this `comparison_func` in call to qsort:

```
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), comparison_func);
```

or you can declare a `struct` that has option character and the corresponding pointer:

```
typedef struct sortfunc {
    char option;
    int (*comparison_func)(const void *, const void *);
} SORTFUNC;

SORTFUNC sort_funcs[] = {
    {'a', a},
    {'d', d},
    {0,   0}
};
```

then go through this array finding the matching option character:

```
SORTFUNC *i;
for (i = sort_funcs; i->option && i->option != c; i++);
if (! i->comparison_func) {
    printf("choice %c is invalid\n", c);
}
else {
    qsort(..., i->comparison_func);
}
```